# Access 2D packed array as if it were one dimensional

Tags: arrays, memory, system-verilog

I have a packed array which is used to hold a series of words, like this:

```
reg [31:0][79:0] H;
```

As I understand, packed arrays are stored as a contiguous block of memory, and so I'm wondering if there is a way to access the values as if they were declared in a 1 dimensional array like this:

```
H[500] <= x;
```

Which would be the same as `H[11][15] <= x`.Is this possible?  I need to fill various blocks within the array that are not at word boundaries, so this would make things much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a packed union

```
union packed {
         logic [31:0][79:0] words;
         lofic [0:2559]     bits;
         logic [7:0][319:0] bytes;
} H;
```

Then the following would be equivalent if the math is correct

```
H.words[11][15] <= x;
H.bits[500] <=x;
```